# How to rectify "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick"?

Tags: java, android

The errors as seen in logcat are:-

```
    2019-02-26 17:19:49.253 31623-31623/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-02-26 17:20:20.717 31623-31623/com.ms.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mohitsharma.myapplication, PID: 31623
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12693)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26101)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12693) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26101) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7
        at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:318)
        at com.mohitsharma.myapplication.MainActivity.onButtonClick1(MainActivity.java:62)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12693) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26101) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

My code is :-

```
package com.mohitsharma.myapplication;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onButtonClick(View v)
    {
        EditText e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);  // volume of the part
        EditText e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2); //Cost of the part
        EditText e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3); //Lead time
        EditText e4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4); //Tolerance
        EditText e5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5); //Number of parts
        EditText e6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        double volume=Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
        double conventional_cost=Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());
        double lead_time=Double.parseDouble(e3.getText().toString());
        double tolerance=Double.parseDouble(e4.getText().toString());
        double num_parts=Double.parseDouble(e5.getText().toString());
        String material=e6.getText().toString();
        AssetManager am=getAssets();
        Workbook wb =null;
        try (InputStream is = am.open("Printer Specification.xls")) {
            wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert wb != null;
        Sheet s=wb.getSheet(0);
        int row=s.getRows();
        int[] x=new int[2];
        List<Integer> possible_printers = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> possible_printers_2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> possible_printers_3 = new ArrayList<>();
        int count=0;
        for(int i=1;i<row;i++)
        {
            count=0;
            Cell c=s.getCell(i,1);  //Checking for print volume vs part volume
            String st=c.getContents();
            int length=st.length();
            for(int j=0;j<length;j++)
            {
                if(st.charAt(j)=='x')
                {
                    x[count]=j;     // Finding the location of x in volume of the printer
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(x[1]!=0)
            {
                double l= Double.parseDouble(st.substring(0,x[0]-1));
                double b= Double.parseDouble(st.substring(x[0]+2,x[1]-1));      //Checking for the cartesian printers volume
                double h=Double.parseDouble(st.substring(x[1]+2));
                double vol=l*b*h;
                if(vol>=volume)
                {
                    possible_printers.add(i);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                double d=Double.parseDouble(st.substring(0,x[0]-2));
                double h=Double.parseDouble(st.substring(x[0]+2,length-1));     // Checking for the volume of the delta printer
                double vol=Math.PI*Math.pow(d,2)*h;
                if (vol>=volume)
                {
                    possible_printers.add(i);
                }
            }

        }
        int[] y=new int[2];
        count=0;
        if (possible_printers.size()>0)     // Checking for the build rate
        {
            for(int i=0;i<possible_printers.size();i++)
            {
                Cell c=s.getCell(possible_printers.get(i),4);
                String st=c.getContents();
                if(!st.equals(""))
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<st.length();j++)
                    {
                        if (st.charAt(j)=='c')
                        {
                            y[count]=j;     //Finding the location of cm3/hr in build rate
                            //count++;
                        }
                    }
                    double build_rate=Double.parseDouble(st.substring(0,y[0]-1));
                    double print_time=(volume/1000)/build_rate;
                    if (lead_time>=print_time)      // Comparing the printing time vs the lead time
                    {
                        possible_printers_2.add(possible_printers.get(i));
                    }
                }
                //count=0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            String print="The part cannot be 3D printed as the part volume is too big";
            t1.setText(print);
            return;         // Display that there are no suitable printers to print your part due to build volume
        }

        if (possible_printers_2.size()>0)       // Check for whether the required tolerance is achieved using printing
        {
            for(int i=0;i<possible_printers_2.size();i++)
            {
                Cell c=s.getCell(possible_printers_2.get(i),3);
                String st=c.getContents();
                double tol=Double.parseDouble(st);
                if (tol<=tolerance)
                {
                    possible_printers_3.add(possible_printers_2.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            String print="The part cannot be 3D printed as printing time is too big";
            t1.setText(print);
            return;     //Display that the given part is not printable due to time issues
        }
        if(possible_printers_3.size()==0)
        {
            String print="The part cannot be 3D printed as the required tolerance cannot be achieved";
            t1.setText(print);
            return;     //Display that the part is not printable as the possible tolerance cannot be achieved by printing
        }

        // COST OF PRINTING

        double cost=0;
        Workbook wb2 = null;
        try (InputStream is2 = am.open("Cost of material.xls")) {
            wb2 = Workbook.getWorkbook(is2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert wb2 != null;
        Sheet s2=wb2.getSheet(0);
        int row2=s2.getRows();
        Workbook wb3=null;
        try (InputStream is3 = am.open("Material densities.xls")) {
            wb3 = Workbook.getWorkbook(is3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert wb3 != null;
        Sheet s3=wb3.getSheet(0);
        int row3=s3.getRows();
        double density=0;
        for(int i=0;i<row3;i++)
        {
            Cell c=s3.getCell(i,0);
            String mat=c.getContents();
            if(mat.equalsIgnoreCase(material))
            {
                Cell c2=s3.getCell(i,1);
                density=Double.parseDouble(c2.getContents());
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int i=1;i<row2;i++)
        {
            Cell c=s2.getCell(i,0);     //Getting the material name
            String mat=c.getContents();
            if(mat.equalsIgnoreCase(material))
            {
                Cell c2=s2.getCell(i,1);        //Getting the filament diameter
                double dia=Double.parseDouble(c2.getContents());
                if(dia==3)
                {
                    Cell c3=s2.getCell(i,2);
                    cost=(volume*density/Math.pow(10,9))*Double.parseDouble(c3.getContents())*70.99*num_parts;
                }
            }
        }
        if(cost<=conventional_cost)
        {
            String print="The part is 3D printable as the printing cost "+cost+" is less than conventional cost "+conventional_cost;
            t1.setText(print);//Display that the part is printable as cost of printing is suitable
        }
        else
        {
            String print="The part is not 3D printable as the printing cost "+cost+" is more than conventional cost "+conventional_cost;
            t1.setText(print);
            return;// Display that part is not printable due to cost issues
        }
        for(int i=0;i<possible_printers_3.size();i++)
        {
            Cell c=s.getCell(possible_printers_3.get(i),0);
            String printer=c.getContents();
            printer=printer+"\n";
            t1.setText(printer);
        }
    }
}
```

The code and error message can be seen above. The code compares some data from the user input with the data in the excel files which are present in the asset folder in the app code. jxl is used to read and write the file in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on line 62 of your Activity. Line 62 is this one:

`Cell c=s.getCell(i,1);  //Checking for print volume vs part volume`

Set a Breakpooint at this line and debug your App. You want to access position 7 in the Array, however it only has a length of 7.

Maybe your `int row=s.getRows();` should be `int row=s.getRows() - 1;` (line 53)?